# About performance and speed

Tags: c++

I have a class (A), which is used in different threads. Only this class uses another class (B). Now I inherit or allocate memory for an object a class B in class A.
But I think it would be better if I pass an object of class B as a parameter to the constructor of A. In this case would not need to constantly create or inherit a class B in class A. It seems to me that it would be faster.

So it will be better in terms of speed and performance?

```
 class B {
  public: int i;
  B() {
     i = 123;
  }
  ~B() {}
  int get() const { return i; }
}


//first solutions
class A:public B {
public: int j;
A() {}
~A() {}
int somethingMethod(int n) {
  j = get() * n;
  return j;
}
}

A * a1 = new A(); //for example
cout << a1->somethingMethod(1) << endl;
cout << a1->somethingMethod(14) << endl;
A * a2 = new A();
cout << a1->somethingMethod(45) << endl;
A * a3 = new A();
cout << a1->somethingMethod(12) << endl;
cout << a1->somethingMethod(24) << endl;
cout << a1->somethingMethod(41) << endl;
A * a4 = new A(); //etc.
cout << a1->somethingMethod(41) << endl;

delete a1, a2, a3, a4;

//second solution
class A: {
public: int j;
B * b;
A(B * _b):b(_b) {}
~A() {}
int somethingMethod(int n) {
  j = b->get() * n;
  return j;
}
}

B * b = new B();
A * a1 = new A(b); //for example
cout << a1->somethingMethod(1) << endl;
cout << a1->somethingMethod(14) << endl;
A * a2 = new A(b);
cout << a1->somethingMethod(45) << endl;
A * a3 = new A(b);
cout << a1->somethingMethod(12) << endl;
cout << a1->somethingMethod(24) << endl;
cout << a1->somethingMethod(41) << endl;
A * a4 = new A(b); //etc.
cout << a1->somethingMethod(41) << endl;

delete b, a1, a2, a3, a4;
```

Comment: please provide a code example

Comment: Profile it.
Anyways, post code for illustration purposes please.

Comment: Can multiple instances of class A use the same instance of class B?

Comment: @MrDuk, http://pastebin.com/3y83kJFi

Comment: Your two versions are potentially completely different in semantics, especially if threads are involved and the As end up sharing a same B object. You can't compare their performance since they don't do the same thing at all.

Comment: @Mat These two versions will do the same thing, only in the second access to the methods of class B will be in objB->method(), and in the first as usual through this->method()

Comment: So B contains no data members? Or that function is `const` and/or doesn't require any synchronization/doesn't access or mutate B's state?

Comment: @Mat Class B will contain the data, but they will be used only for reading. Data of class A can be overwritten. Hence I create n objects of class A.

Comment: Please [edit] a more complete description of your scenario into your question. As it is it doesn't explain half of what it should. A reduced example that illustrates what both classes do would be ideal.

Comment: @Mat I have edited the code more understandable. What is the best solutions in terms of speed and accuracy?

Comment: My _guess_ is that your second version will have one more indirect access, hence potentially slower. To be sure: benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 things that you need to consider -

1. You are saying that your class A is accessed by multiple threads. Your sample code looks ok but if that is just some pseudo code you mocked up to ask the question then you need to make sure that your classes are thread safe. In your case you are only reading values but if there are read/ writes happening concurrently from multiple threads then make sure to use some thread synchronization objects to sync them.
2. Now talking about speed and performance. Your sample class does not seem to be doing much. I don't see the need to write class. An inline function would probably be best as well (considering this is not some mocked up code). Even if you use inheritance it should not hurt you as long as you are not using virtual function where there is an extra overhead to look up in the vtable and deference the pointer if you really care up to that much detail.
3. If class B is just an implementation detail then I would not pass it as a parameter to the contructor.